# DFS Java implementation: how to write "Element in deque/stack"

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, depth-first-search

I am stuck in the middle of a line in DFS java implementation: how can I express "a vertex in a deque/stack?"

**I need to write a line in the for loop to express vertex "u" is in the deque/stack. The initial value is the first item of "toExplore".**

Below is my code:

```
public List<Integer> DepthFirstList(Integer v)
{
    List<Integer> vertices = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    Deque<Integer> toExplore = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(); //The deque,used as the stack in DFS
    List<Integer> visited = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    toExplore.push(v);
    visited.add(v);
    while(!toExplore.isEmpty())
    {
        boolean hasNeighbor=false;
        for()//To be more precise, u should be a vertex never visited. How can I make this change?
        {
            if(g.hasEdge(v, u)) 
            {
                toExplore.push(u);
                visited.add(u);
                hasNeighbor=true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(hasNeighbor==false) 
        {
            toExplore.pop();
            vertices.add(v);
        }
        else hasNeighbor=false;
    }
    return vertices;
}
```

Comment: `v = toExplore.pop()`, then loop over the edges from `v`. Is there some sort of `getAllEdges` or `getAllNeighbours` function?

Comment: You're better off maintaining a separate `Set` of visited vertices.

Comment: @Dukeling There is a function called `TreeMap<Integer,Integer> getAdjList(Integer v)` which returns the adjacency list of a particular vertex.

Comment: What exactly does this `TreeMap` contain? I would think `v,u` for each neighbour `u`, but that can't be as each entry will overwrite each other (because it's a `Map`).

Comment: @Dukeling There is only one line of code `return adjList.get(v)`. The `adjList` is a private variable defined as `adjList = new ArrayList<TreeMap<Integer, Integer>>();
    for (int i=0; i<numVertices; i++) {
      adjList.add(new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>());`

Comment: And how do entries get added to each of the `TreeMap`s?

Comment: @Dukeling I did not see any other lines of code about `.add`. There is  function about `addEdge`, though. Not quite relevant.

Comment: `addEdge` is probably relevant. You should probably look for something like `adjList.get(...).put(...)` (or using temporary variables).

Comment: @Dukeling `public void addEdge(Integer v, Integer w, int wgt) {
    adjList.get(v).put(w, wgt);
    adjList.get(w).put(v, wgt);
    numEdges++;
  }` That is all of it.

Comment: Yes there is line `adjList.get(v).put(w, wgt)`. How is that relevant to the line I want to implement? @Dukeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing your for-loop with the below should work:

```
v = toExplore.peek();
for (int u: getAdjList(v).keySet())
{
   if (!visited.contains(u))
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

It seems like the adjacency list contains a mapping of the other vertex index to the edge weight, so the `keySet` would give us a list of all the vertices.

Some random notes:

- I would recommend a recursive method, if you're allowed. It's a lot simpler once you get your head around recursion (which is definitely a good thing to be comfortable with in the long run). But writing recursive algorithms non-recursively is certainly good programming practice.
- As Louis mentioned, making `visited` a `Set` (`HashSet`) would be much better, if able. This would allow for expected `O(1)` (constant time) lookup, as opposed to `O(n)` (linear time).
- Also, I'd probably make `toExplore` a `Stack` as you'd only be using stack-based methods.